# Vertx mysql client asynchronous and synchronou

Tags: vert.x

I need help on the vertx mysql client v4.1.0 java api. I have used the two codes below however I am getting inconsistent results with number 2 as it returns nulls even when there is a database record. Is it not a blocking call??

```
/* 1. asynchronous */
mysql.query(sql).execute(asr -> {
    if (asr.succeeded()) {
        RowSet<Row> rowset = asr.result();
    }else{
       //Log and handle error
    }
});


/* 2. ??? synchronous */
RowSet<Row> rowset = mysql.query(sql).execute().result();
```

Comment: Ignore the question. Should have read documentation. its a future !!!

Comment: The .result() of the operation will be null if the operation failed.

Answer (score 0):

Both `.reactivex` and raw *Vert.x* *MySQL* client library variants are asynchronous by design providing a `Handler` base type as a way to handle SQL queries results:

> io.vertx.sqlclient.Query#execute(Handler<AsyncResult> handler)
> Execute the query.

*Vert.x* still provides API portability to common patterns such as *Java*'s `Future` and here down the method signature:

> io.vertx.sqlclient.Query#execute()
> Like execute(Handler) but returns a Future of the asynchronous result

The *Reactive* client library port provides an rxfied method as well returning query results as a publisher `Single`:

> io.vertx.reactivex.sqlclient.Query#rxExecute()
> Execute the query.

With above considerations in mind, when calling:

```java
RowSet<Row> rowset = mysql.query(sql).execute().result();
```

You are executing the SQL query and then blocking the current thread until the query result is returned and the `Future` is resolved.

Comment: Thanks. that explains it.